# Где установить groupId (int), которое можно использовать в методе setGroupVisible?

Tags: android, android-menu, android-resources

Как в Android при создании меню через графический редактор для группы пунктов устанавливается groupId (int), которое можно использовать в методе `setGroupVisible` или `setGroupEnabled`?

Как поставить через `add` для `onCreateOptionsMenu` знаю, не могу разобраться как через атрибуты group установить.

Answer (score 0):

Предположим, у вас есть меню с четыремя элементами. Третий и четветрый элемент находятся внутри группы `group1`:

```xml
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:title="Item1" />
    <item android:title="Item2" />
    <group android:id="@+id/group1">
        <item android:title="Item3" />
        <item android:title="Item4" />
    </group>
</menu>
```

Чтобы скрыть группу, нужно вызвать метод [`setGroupVisible`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Menu#setGroupVisible(int,%20boolean)) у меню, передав туда идентификатор группы:

```kotlin
menu.setGroupVisible(R.id.group1, false)
```

А чтобы сделать элементы группы неактивными, используйте [`setGroupEnabled`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Menu#setGroupEnabled(int,%20boolean)):

```kotlin
menu.setGroupEnabled(R.id.group1, false)
```

Comment: Спасибо, а то я подставлял числовое значение  идентификатора.